# How to insert multiple rows at once without using inputs in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

How to insert the datas from a `<table>` rows into the database without any `<input>` ?

In CodeIgniter, I have a function where I can generate random users, which are inserted into the `<table>...</table>` using an AJAX method by clicking on a `$('#btnGenerate');`

It fills out an empty table with the new table rows (`<tr>`).  Here how it looks like:
[image: Random user generator]

Now when I want to save these new rows into the database, I don't know how to proceed. As far as I know, I need to have an array which will be then posted into the form's action: `members/form_random` for example with the `$this->input->post('someInputName');?>`. How can I do that if I don't use any `<input>` tags inside the table ?

Any advice for solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you generate the random users, make sure you store each row in an object array like

```
var arr = [
    {username:'abc',email:'abc@exmaple.org'},
    {username:'def',email:'def@exmaple.org'},
     .
     .
];
```

And the trigger an onClick event from the Apply,Save Button to an AJAX function and send the array as JSON data to the controller that saves the data.

I think this will sort out your problem..

Comment: thank you for your tip, i managed to work it out by using your tip